Why my %(exp) in org-agenda-prefix-format isn't it working?
I am trying to format my category string so it appears shorter in the agenda.
All my categories look like that: foo bar - string I wanna keep. My goal is to remove the foo bar -  bit at the begining.
Looking through info pages, and a few examples inline I could make a function work this way:
(nth 1 (split-string "foo bar - string   I wanna keep" " - "))

This returns the string "string I wanna keep", but adding this function to the org-agenda-prefix-format returns a wrong argument stringp nil
(defun my/org-agenda-format-category ()
  (nth 1 (split-string (org-get-category) " - ")))

  (setq org-agenda-prefix-format '(
         (agenda . " %t %s %i %(my/org-agenda-format-category)" )
         (todo . " %i %-12:c")
         (tags . " %i %-12:c")
         (search . " %i %-12:c")
))

Looking around, I see that the error means that some of my files are not correctly formatted, and the function returns nil instead of the expected string.
My first thought was some of my files category fields are not correctly formatted, so it returns nil instead of a string and throws an error. So I added some kind of error handling:
(defun my/org-agenda-format-category ()
  (let ((my-category (nth 1 (split-string (org-get-category) " - "))))
  (if my-category
      my-category
    "my/format-category Error"
      )))

This function works well when I call it from the Eval prompt with the cursor pointing to an org file, it returns the formatted category, or the 'error message' as intended.
If I add it to org-agenda-prefix-format though I get the same error again.
Thinking about it some more, it does not make sense that the nil value throws an error at the agenda command level, since it handles it for all built in elements. Anyway, with this function, it should not happen.
Using org-get-category might be the problem, so I tried the following, and it works:
  (setq org-agenda-prefix-format '(
         (agenda . " %t %s %i %(org-get-category)" )
         (todo . " %i %-12:c")
         (tags . " %i %-12:c")
         (search . " %i %-12:c")
))

Looking a config on Github linked by a Reddit user answering a similar question, I noticed the use of org-with-point-at-org-buffer.
So I thought maybe using an outside function is the problem, and the 'pointer' or the org buffer is not available to the function. So I tried the user's function modifying their SUMMARY property by another custom property I actually use in my files. I get the same exact error:
(defun yant/format-summary-for-agenda ()
  "Format the contents of :SUMMARY: property to show in agenda view."
  (let ((summary (org-with-point-at-org-buffer (org-entry-get (point) "SUMMARY"))))
    (if (not (seq-empty-p summary))
    (format "[%s] " summary)
      "")))

To make sure passing the org buffer or file to my my/org-agenda-format-category function was not the problem, I tried simplifying it as follows:
(defun my/org-agenda-format-category ()
      (org-get-category))

And this works!
I just cannot understand why this works, and the following does not..
(defun my/org-agenda-format-category ()
  (nth 1 (split-string (org-get-category) " - ")))

I have just found out about the toggle-debug-on-error command, so I am adding the debug message, maybe it can help. I personally cannot see where something goes wrong there.
I will also add that so far I was testing using a custom-agenda-view which was completely failing. Using the built-in agenda command from dispatch actually displays the formatted categories corrctly, but still throws an error.
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  string-match(" - " nil 0)
  split-string(nil " - ")
  (nth 1 (split-string (org-get-category) " - "))
  (let ((my-category (nth 1 (split-string (org-get-category) " - ")))) (if my-category my-category "my/format-category Error"))
  my/org-agenda-format-category()
  (org-eval (my/org-agenda-format-category))
  (format "%s" (org-eval (my/org-agenda-format-category)))
  (format " %s %s %s %s" (format "%s" (if (member time '("" nil)) "" (concat time "" (get-text-property 0 'extra-space time)))) (format "%s" (if (member extra '("" nil)) "" (concat extra "" (get-text-property 0 'extra-space extra)))) (format "%s" (if (member category-icon '("" nil)) "" (concat category-icon "" (get-text-property 0 'extra-space category-icon)))) (format "%s" (org-eval (my/org-agenda-format-category))))
  eval((format " %s %s %s %s" (format "%s" (if (member time '("" nil)) "" (concat time "" (get-text-property 0 'extra-space time)))) (format "%s" (if (member extra '("" nil)) "" (concat extra "" (get-text-property 0 'extra-space extra)))) (format "%s" (if (member category-icon '("" nil)) "" (concat category-icon "" (get-text-property 0 'extra-space category-icon)))) (format "%s" (org-eval (my/org-agenda-format-category)))) t)
  org-agenda-format-item(nil "" nil "" nil "06:00")
  org-agenda-add-time-grid-maybe((... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) 10 t)
  org-agenda-list(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda-list nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda-list)
  org-agenda(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda nil nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda)



So org-get-category returns nil for some entry, probably the time grid entries. You can catch that and return perhaps the empty string. See the edited answer.

Try:
(defun my/org-agenda-format-category ()
  (let ((cat (org-get-category)))
     (if (not cat)
         ""
       (let ((split (split-string cat " - ")))
          (if (= (length split) 1)
              cat
            (nth 1 split))))

It now checks the category first: if it is nil then it returns the empty string. Otherwise, it tries to split the category on - and if it succeeds, the split will have more than one element, but if not it will only have one. In the latter case, return the category, otherwise return the second element as you do in your function. That way, you'll never have a nil value: it will always be either the full category or a part of it.

Thanks for your input. I did more testing but did not get the time to report back here. I edited my original post. It turns out it might not be an error handling issue after all. I still have no idea what is the problem though.

I tested your code to see if it was working better, and I get the same error. I added the 'stacktrace' from toggle-debug-on-error, maybe it can help.

Your backtrace shows that the category that org-get-category returns was nil, so I edited the function to check for that and return the empty string "" in that case, before going on and checking the split.

Thank you it works fine now. Modifying your code to return an error message instead of an empty string, I can see it was actually the empty lines in the time grid throwing an error. I thought empty time grid lines were only cosmetic place holders. Got to read more about that.
